# Django Rest Framework - NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.11.7 with DjangoRestFramework 3.7.3

I have a app **meals**

meals/urls.py

```
app_name = 'meals'

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^$', views.api_root),
    url(r'^food/$', views.FoodList.as_view(), name='food-list'),
    url(r'^food/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FoodDetail.as_view(), name='food-detail'),
])
```

meals/views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'Foods': reverse('food-list', request=request, format=format),
    })
```

When I run, I'm getting the error NoReverseMatch.

But if I removed `app_name = 'meals'` in urls.py, it works

```
# app_name = 'meals'

    urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
        url(r'^$', views.api_root),
        url(r'^food/$', views.FoodList.as_view(), name='food-list'),
        url(r'^food/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.FoodDetail.as_view(), name='food-detail'),
    ])
```

How do I get it working while keeping app_name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `app_name = 'meals'`, then you have to include the app name when you reverse the urls:

```
reverse('meals:food-list', request=request, format=format),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it from your apps.py file